# Load EToken Certificate in ANY Browser

Tags: java, firefox, encryption, keytool

I am working on an applicaion which does authentication based on EToken (Specifically we are using aladdin eTokens). Previously we are using just normal (File Certificates) certificates to which were added in clients browser, and its working well with Mozilla and Internet Explorer, we are using applet to load the certificates in the browser.

Now, the problem comes with the eToken it also load the certificates when we insert the device into the machine but I am not able to load the particular certificate in Mozilla Firefox the same applet code is working fine with IE. In firefox I am getting error something like **java.security.InvalidKeyException: Unsupported key type: null**  that says that the private/public key is null, Mozilla is not able to access the keys of the eToken Certificate.

If you got any clue please help me out.

Comment: Did you get the browser show a dialog to user choose a certificate? Regards,
Alberto Yano

Comment: Alberto I have created my own popup to show all the certificates which are installed in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is more related with `pkcs11.cfg`

Check configuration file

```
${java.home}/lib/security/pkcs11.cfg
```

It should help you.

Comment: @com.status.live: It is suggested to accept the helpful answer close the question. So, It may help to others in future.